# How to replace PHP variable with powershell?

Tags: php, powershell

I have to replace my PHP variable with powershell. The variable is `$env = "TEST"` but with powershell I want to replace it to `$env = "TEST"` because of using Azure Releases. Currently I am having a sript like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\MyProject\MyBuildOutputs\connect.php') | 
Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '$env = "TEST"', '$env = "PROD"' } | 
Set-Content -Path 'C:\MyProject\MyBuildOutputs\connect.php' -Force
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know why.

How do I do that?

Comment: _" it doesn't work"_  What result do you actually get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Powershell's `-replace` expects a regex pattern. `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, it is the end of line anchor. So the command is looking at pattern that's

```
 end of line, followed by env = "TEST"
```

To use dollar sign as a literal character, either escape it `\$`, or use the `[regex]` type accelereator to access `escape()` and let Powershell do the escaping. Like so,

```
$_ -replace [regex]::escape('$env = "TEST"'), '$env = "PROD"'
```